# ReactJS TypeError: Undefined is not a function (near'..users.maps..')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new at React and trying to learn it. I am getting data from API and I will use the data.It just returns array list data. Please help me to solve this problem, The log says it's coming from the users.map loop in the JSX. I want to display the data on the user const and become an array list

```
const Item = ({user_id, title, body}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>User Id :{user_id}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Tittle :{title}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Body :{body}
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.line}></View>
        </View>
    )

}


const Berita = () => {
    const [users,
        setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    const getData = () => {
        axios
            .get('https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/posts')
            .then(res => {
                console.log('res: ', res);
                setUsers(res.data);
            })
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {users.map(user => {
                return <Item 
                key={user.id} 
                user_id={user.user_id} 
                title={user.title} 
                body={user.body}/>
            })}
        </View>

    )
}

export default Berita
```

thank for your time

Comment: The response from your API isn't an array, it is an object. So you're setting `users` to an object, which doesn't have a `.map()` method. It also isn't very clear what  `selectItem` is supposed to be used for or why it looks like it is setting a component as its state?

Comment: select item is not supposed to be use , i forgot to delete thats code ,

Comment: Thank You verryyy much nickk, iam new in react, i just follow the tutorial video, without understand it, it so helpfull what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing:

```
const getData = () => {
  axios
    .get('https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/posts')
    .then(res => {
      setUsers(res.data.data); // <-- change to `res.data.data`
    });
}
```

Your issue is that `res.data` isn't what you think it is. It is actually an object and not an array, so when trying to use `.map()` on an object, you get an error as `.map()` isn't a method p natively part of an object.

When using `axios.get()`, you get back a Promise that resolves to a [response object](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) which has the following shape:

> The response for a request contains the following information.
>
> ```
> {
>   // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
>   data: {},
>
>   // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
>   status: 200,
>
>   // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
>   statusText: 'OK',
>
>   // `headers` the HTTP headers that the server responded with
>   // All header names are lower cased and can be accessed using the bracket notation.
>   // Example: `response.headers['content-type']`
>   headers: {},
>
>   // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
>   config: {},
>
>   // `request` is the request that generated this response
>   // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)
>   // and an XMLHttpRequest instance in the browser
>   request: {}
> }
> ```

In your example, the `res` in `.then(res =>`  is an object of this structure, and it is the `data` property of this response object that holds the body/data that your API responds with. In your example, the above object's `data` property holds:

```
{
  "meta": {
    /* ... properties ... */
  },
  "data": [/* user objects */ {...}, {...}, ...]
}
```

So, to correctly access your array of user objects from the object object, you first need to access `res.data` which gives you access to the above object, and then `.data` (by using `res.data.data`) to get access to the array of user objects from the object.