# What's the problem when trying to render the cards?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to render multiple cards by pulling data from the API. But the return is an array, I don't understand why the map is not working.

```
const CharacterCard = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

  const openModal = () => {
    setShowModal(prev => !prev)
  }

  const characters = useRequestData([], `${BASE_URL}/characters`)

  const renderCard = characters.map((character) => {
    return (
      <CardContainer key={character._id} imageUrl={character.imageUrl} />
    )
  })

  return (
    <Container>
      {renderCard}
      <ModalScreen showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default CharacterCard
```

The hook is this

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

const useRequestData = (initialState, url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.data)
      })
  }, [url])

  return (data)
}

export default useRequestData
```

---

Console error:

[image: console error image]

Requisition return:

[image: requisition return image]

API: https://disneyapi.dev/docs

Comment: Same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70483693/5648954)

Answer (score 2):

If you notice the [axios response schema](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema), the `data` entry "is the response that was provided by the server".

[Disney API](https://disneyapi.dev/docs) response includes the `data` entry too.

Therefore, you actually wanted to get Disney data and not the axios response, fix it to:

```
setData(res.data.data)
```

You could debugged it by logging `console.log(res)` or going backward in the error chain `console.log(characters)` should result `{data: [...]}`, which hints that you can't execute `.map` on an object.