# "Uncaught TypeError: .map is not a function" while trying to display fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I wanted to fetch and display some data from api using axios. When i try to map it, it says that pools.map is not a function.

My code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function FetchPools() {

  const [pools, setPools] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('https://yields.llama.fi/pools')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data)
          setPools(res.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }, []);
    
  return (
      <>
        <ul>
          {
            pools.map(element=>
              <li
                key={element.chain}
              >
              {element.project}
              </li>
            )
          }
        </ul>
      </>
    )
  }

export default FetchPools
```

I would greatly appreciate if anybody got any ideas how to make this work.
Thanks in advance

I tried to set key value in pools.map to "chains" because response data doesnt have "Id" attribute in it.
Second thing is, I checked if pools is an array with "Array.isArray(pools)" and it says that pre-return pools is "True", but when I try it after return then it is "False".

Comment: I guess you want `res.data.data`, the first `data` is added by axios, and the second `.data` is from the response.

Comment: Also the API returns an object, and it contains a property `data` which is an array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS TypeError: Undefined is not a function (near'..users.maps..')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70483808)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure whether this works but as I had this problem, I solved it by creating a function which was fetching the API and then called this function on useEffect.
I was able to console log everything in this new function until I got the error tracked down.